# Angular 7 first object not getting pushed properly into the array

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs

I have a chat app. I make a new connection and then send them the message: `hello`, the person I am sending that message to, is receiving the message and is showing on their mobile screen. On my phone, however, it is not showing on my screen, and inside the observable subscription all that is getting through is `[]`. Then when I close the window that I am talking to the partner with and reopen it, all the messages that were sent before, show up on my screen and then sending more messages has the desired effect.

component.ts

```js
public messages$: Message[] - [];
private _messages: Subscription;

  public ngOnInit(): void {
    this._messages = this.chatService.messages$().subscribe((message: Message[]): void => {
      console.log('message received in subscription', message);
      this.messages$ = message;
      this.scrollToBottom();
    });
  }

  private ngOnDestroy(): void {
    this._messages.unsubscribe();
  }
```

chat.service.ts

```js
 private messages: Message[] = new Array<Message>();
  private readonly bsMessages$: BehaviorSubject<Message[]> = new BehaviorSubject<Message[]>(this.messages);


  public messages$(): Observable<Message[]> {
    this.socket.fromEvent<Message>('message').subscribe((msg: Message): void => {
      if (msg.image) {
        msg.image = msg.image.replace('*', 'png');
        this.activeConversation.messages.push(msg);
        this.bsMessages$.next(this.messages);
        this.conversationStorage.set(this.activeConversation.id, this.activeConversation);
      } else {
        this.activeConversation.messages.push(msg);
        this.bsMessages$.next(this.messages);
        this.conversationStorage.set(this.activeConversation.id, this.activeConversation);
      }
    });
    return this.bsMessages$.asObservable();
  }

  public async sendMessage(msg: Message): Promise<void> {
    if (this.cameraPath) {
      await this.base64.encodeFile(this.cameraPath).then((base64File: string): void => {
        msg.image = base64File.replace('*', 'png');
        this.socket.emit('message', msg);
      });
      msg.image = this.webView.convertFileSrc(this.cameraPath);
    }
    await this.socket.emit('message', msg);
    this.activeConversation.messages.push(msg);
    this.bsMessages$.next(this.messages);
    this.conversationStorage.set(this.activeConversation.id, this.activeConversation);
  }

  public async setAsActiveConversation(user: Contact): Promise<void> {
    const { id } = user;
    this.activeConversation = await this.conversationStorage.get(id);
    if (this.activeConversation === null) {
      await this._newConversation(doctor);
      await this.conversationStorage.set(id, this.activeConversation);
    } else {
      this.activeConversation.messages.forEach((msg: Message): void => {
        if (msg.image) {
          msg.image = this.webView.convertFileSrc(msg.image);
        } else {
          msg.image = '';
        }
      });
      this.messages = this.activeConversation.messages;
      this.bsMessages$.next(this.messages);
    }
  }
```

thank you for any help

Comment: in chat.service.ts, where is `this.messages` set? should it not be `this.bsMessages$.next(msg);` ?

Comment: I'll update the code so you can see that.

Comment: @enno.void also you can only call `.next()` on the Subject that you declared the new BehaviourSubject with